# Importing library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SeleniumLibrary' In VS Code

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, robotframework

Issue is recurring in **VS Code**

```
Error in file 'd:File Location' on line 2: Importing library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SeleniumLibrary'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  c:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.35.0\src\robotframework_debug_adapter
  D:\Vector.ai\qa-automation-ui
  c:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.35.0\src
  c:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.35.0\src\robotframework_ls\vendored
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\python38.zip
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\DLLs
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\lib
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\lib\site-packages
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'd:\Vector.ai\qa-automation-ui\KeyWords.robot' on line 2: Importing library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SeleniumLibrary'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  None
PYTHONPATH:
  c:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.35.0\src\robotframework_debug_adapter
  D:\Vector.ai\qa-automation-ui
  c:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.35.0\src
  c:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions\robocorp.robotframework-lsp-0.35.0\src\robotframework_ls\vendored
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\python38.zip
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\DLLs
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\lib
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063
  C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it? `pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary`

Answer (score 4):

First should be run this command in the command prompt to install the `seleniumlibrary` in the system:

```
pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary
```

Then, you need to configure your **Robocorp** Code and **Robot Framework Language Server extensions** Python path in your Visual Studio Code then restart the Visual Studio Code and then execute your program.

Please refer to the official documentation: https://pypi.org/project/robotframework-seleniumlibrary

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in vscode with robocorp extensions.
This fixed the issue for me:
In vscode command palette (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>), search for "Robocorp: Create Robot" and created a "standard Robot Framework Template".
Now try running tests with Robocorp extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the error message, that robocorp extension is using its own python instance and so it is using packages from
`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\robocorp\holotree\b1f3c244e_9679c063\lib\site-packages` where seleniumlibrary is not installed.

You need to configure your **Robocorp Code** and **Robot Framework Language Server** extensions python path. When you do that, your extensions will be able to see packages (including selenium library) you installed to your python instance. You can configure your extensions in VS Code settings.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue for both *selenium library* and *appium library*. The solution for me was to disable the *robocorp extension* and reload the window, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, only using VS Code developing for `RobotFramework` and it presented the message

```
"Unresolved library: SeleniumLibrary. Error generating libspec:
Importing library 'SeleniumLibrary' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SeleniumLibrary' Consider adding the needed paths to the "robot.pythonpath" setting and calling the "Robot Framework: Clear caches and restart" action.".
```

The solution was to disable the `Robocorp Code` plugin which stopped the error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).